# Trajectory Game Development Libraries for android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am going to develop 2D trajectory game in android by using Maths and 
Physics. I don't want to use any type of engine for game development. Is there any animation library in android for effects like trajectory.
[image]

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Check out Rebound that Facebook has build. It pretty nice. http://facebook.github.io/rebound/

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: You can use rebound to calculate that curve.